# Python, Pandas: Access multiple columns in lambda-function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Good day,

I would like to ask if it's possible to access more than one column in a lambda-function inside a pandas-dataframe or if there's an alternative!?

For example my dataframe is looking something like this:

```
value_a  |  value_b  |  value_c
1        |  17       |  8
2        |  253      |  9
3        |  89       |  8
...
```

I also got a function that is calculating with some of the data:

```
def some_function(a, b):
    ...do something:
    return c
```

Now I want to use lambda-function to calculate together with the function but include the data from two columns. Something like this...

```
df['value_d'] = df['value_b'].apply(lambda x: some_function(x, df['value_c']))
```

Is it possible to access more than one column inside such a function or is there a better solution?

Hoping my question is understandable.

Thanks to all of you and have a great day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use apply over whole df

```
df['value_d'] = df.apply(lambda row: some_function(row['value_b'],row['value_c']), axis=1)
```